# How to make multiple tests and get multiple results all toghether for a variable in one function?

Tags: xml, haskell, functional-programming

i am working with a game board, that maps pieces by coordinates. For this example consider the piece "B" with orientation "N" on the coordinates (0,0). My coordinates are displayed in a pair of String, so my format for the type Piece is a (String, String,(String,String))

So i want my script to be able to decide what the next move will be for a withdraw piece. Example, piece "E". For that i have 4 functions that test if the squares around the piece "B" are empty or not. For this example let's just consider 2 of them.

```
minusx :: Piece -> [Piece] -> Bool
minusx _ [] = False
minusx (a,b,(x,y)) ((w,v,(x1,y1)):ts) = let xm = show (rInt x-1)
                                    in if (xm == x1 && y == y1 ) then True
                                       else minusx (a,b,(x,y)) ts
```

and

```
minusy :: Piece -> [Piece] -> Bool
minusy _ [] = False
minusy (a,b,(x,y)) ((w,v,(x1,y1)):ts) = let ym = show (rInt y-1)
                                    in if (x == x1 && ym == y1 ) then True
                                       else minusx (a,b,(x,y)) ts
```

So if we consider the piece "B" on (0,0), minusx returns false if there isn't any piece in the board with the coordinates (-1,0) and minusy if there isn't any piece in (0,-1).

If they are empty, then another function makes a list of possible plays based on the withdraw piece and orientation of the "B" piece. Lets just make a simple example that we will use for both.

```
possibleplay :: Piece -> WithdrawPiece -> [Piece]    
possibleplay ("B","N",(x,y)) "E" = [("E","N",(x-1,y-1)),("E","S",(x-1,y-1))]
```

Let's imagine it's called possibleplayX possibleplayY for the diferent functions up there, just to get simpler example.

So if we run possibleplayX on the piece ("B","N",(0,0)) for withdraw piece "E" we can play it two diferent ways. ("E","N",(x-1,y-1)) and ("E","S",(x-1,y-1))
And the same goes for possibleplayY. If we concat both, we would have repeated plays but i don't have diferent coordinates here so don't take that in mind.

Now this is where i get stuck. I want to list all the possibilities for all orientations.

I can make one by one with an if.

```
if minusx == False then possibleplayX bla bla bla
```

But i want to make this for all positions around. Imagine that both minusx and minusy were empty. If the result of minusx == False then run possibleplayX and if minusy == False run possibleplayY. I know how to do that one by one but not all at the same time if they are all empty. How can i run both at the same time and concat all the results?

Take in consideration that minusx can be empty but minusy may not.

Thanks for the time to help. :)

EDIT: Just edited the functions to work with types to easier undestanding

```
type Piece = (String,String,(String,String))
type WithdrawPiece = String
```

Comment: Please, please use an ADT for the `(String, String, [String])`. Its way too hard to tell what everything is here.

Comment: I agree with @alternative: start with defining your datatypes. A *lot* of code follows from the datatypes. And don't use "stringly typed" data.

Comment: Ok guys i can do that... but that doesn't help in nothing my problem...

Comment: @Pedro it makes your code readable so we can tell whats going on and help you fix it.

Comment: Shure shure, i understand that. But the functions are working great, i described what they do. I need help to make a function that takes a piece, and runs minusx and minusy in it, and depending on the results runs possibleplayX and possibleplayY. Let me just make a type Piece to represent the String structure.

Comment: Ok it's edited. So i want to make a function called for example "allpossibleplays" that takes list of pieces and it takes the first piece runs minusx and minusy. if minusx if False, it runs possibleplayX, if True, it doesn't return anything. Same goes for minusy. The result should be all the results concatenated in a list of pieces

Comment: Just FYI, you might find my [grid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/grid) package useful. Check out the `Grid` and `GridMap` classes.

Comment: @mhwombat is there a way to see how the functions are build? I don't think i can import nothing to the script, because it's a project i have to deliver and it's tested with some standards. It would probably give some error. But if you could help with the problem that would be great :)

Comment: Yes, you can see all source code on Hackage. From the link I gave you, click on one of the modules, and then click on the "Source" link at the upper right to view the source code. Or if you want to download all the source without installing it, you can get it from [github](https://github.com/mhwombat/grid) - click on the "download zip" button.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `String`s for everything? I'm having trouble keeping track of whether, say, "N" is the name of a piece or it means "North". For example, you could define `type Direction = North | South | East | West`. And if you use `(Int,Int)` for the co-ordinates, then you can easily use a list comprehension to generate all of the neighbours/possible moves for any position.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43891/discussion-between-mhwombat-and-pedro-lino)

Comment: I am parsing a XML file, and all that info is returned as Maybe String. I removed the "Just" so it's just a String. I guess i could put N S E W instead. Pieces have allways the tipe B C N E, orientation N S E W, the coordinates and i have another pair but that's for another step of the game. Oh and i need to display the outcome as it is, so i allways use a putStr ( unlines (etc)) to display it.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to understand your Question and wrote the following hopefully equivalent haskell code.

- But first please take @alternative and @molbdnilo 's advice into account:
  **AVOID String**, Strings are the "cheap" `data` declaration with the possibility that a typo can bite you at runtime, so you avoid your compilers help (- it's a bit like using C IMHO)

so I would declare something like

```
data PieceType = A|B|C|Empty deriving (Eq)
data Direction = N|E|S|W deriving (Eq)
data Piece = Piece { _name::PieceType
                   , _orientation::Direction
                   , _position::(Int,Int)}
```

the underscores I use because it allows me to use @ekmett 's lens library, which you should definitely check out when you have time and resources

- Next use built in functions - your minusx function is essentially a hand coded `any`, and if I am not wrong there is a typo in minusy (at the else branch you are calling minusx).
- Third if you're using tuples Arrows are your friend: Control.Arrow is abstract but useful.

  - (first f) (x, y) == (f x, y)
  - (second g) (x, y) == (x, g y)
  - (f *** g) (x, y) == (f x, g y)

here is a translation of your `minusx`-function

```
minusx :: Piece -> [Piece] -> Bool
minusx p ps = any (\x -> (first (subtract 1) . _position) p == _position x) ps
```

but I would use a different approach as you say you have a problem with stuff being empty and in addition if you want to find something from a list according to some rule one utilises - tadaa - the `filter` function so possible moves should be something like

```
possibleMoves :: Piece -> [Piece] -> [Piece]
possibleMoves p = filter (\x -> (_name x /= Empty)&&(minusx' p x || minusy' p x))
```

with the `minusx'` function being

```
minusx' :: Piece -> Piece -> Bool
minusx' p q = (first (subtract 1) . _position) p == _position q
```

Comment: You are a saint for helping, but you are also an enabler of bad habits, by giving advice before those horrid String uses are removed.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'enabler of bad habits', do you mean it is to much help and too little exploration to be left to @PedroLino ?

Comment: I just mean that the original question-asker really really should have gotten rid of all those Strings before doing anything else, even if that means "tough love" from friends waiting.

Comment: true it is, but even with the hint of using ADT's it is still messy to do the transition from `String` for a beginner

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem using Types instead of Data?

Comment: you should get into the habit of using `data`/`type`/`newtype` as they are checked by the compiler so if you have a typo, your program will not compile, if you use a `String` to do emulate this, the compiler won't raise an error and your program crashes unexpectedly. In addition the types and type-signatures help you structure the program and add in a layer of abstraction which makes reasoning about your program less difficult. Types are one of the strongest features in Haskell, if you don't leverage it you should use something different perl/python which give you more freedom and less safety.

Comment: Shure but why are you criticising me, for not using types if i already changed the code? Don't i have the tipe piece in it? Or do you mean i should change that to a Data?

Comment: yes, the language is a bit misleading - 'a type'='algebraic data type'='data declaration', 'a type *alias*'='type' and 'wrapper type'='newtype', this is a metaphor not a scientific definition. Using the keyword `data` is the one you should use in *most* cases it discribes what something is - `data Direction {-is either-} = North |{-or-} South |{-or-} East | {-or-} West deriving{-and it can-} (Eq){-be checked for equality-}`, a `type` declaration adds a different layer of meaning, e.g. `type Temperature=Double` so my program uses doubles but I see a different intention in the source code.